# How to stop nearest neighbour analysis from connecting points over the north pole in R

Tags: r, coordinates, nearest-neighbor, r-sf, r-sp

I am trying to produce a map by connecting random points on continents. I managed to get close to the desired outcome, but I don't want the points in North America to connect to those in Siberia. But I can't do this using max distance as the points are close, across the North Pole. View the attached plot, to see what I mean.

[image]
This is the code I used for connecting points. `pts` are simply coordinates of the points

`neighbors <- 5`

`nearest <- st_nn(pts, pts, k = neighbors+1, maxdist = 3500000)`

`connect <- st_connect(pts, pts, nearest) %>% st_as_sf`

I then plot the map with

`geom_sf(data = connect, color = 'white') +`

`geom_sf(data = pts, color = 'white', shape = 1, size = 3)`

I tried making separate files for North America, Europe, and Asia, but then the points are not consistent in distance. Unless I should use a different tool to get the points, perhaps generate them directly in R? So far I've used QGIS to generate random points in polygons.

How would you go about solving this?

Cheers!

Comment: The points in Siberia and North America are nearest to one another in terms of distance, and since `st_connect` just calculates straight lines between points, they do connect with a straight line. Not sure I completely understand your intention. Do you need only to remove lines between America and Africa/Europe/Asia? If so, then you can classify the lines according to origin/destination and subset according to a condition. If you can please share sample data, and confirm that is what you had in mind, will try to provide an example.

Comment: Hi, yes that's exactly what I am trying to do - remove the lines between North America and Asia. I am using the file 'points2.csv' for coordinates, it's in my repo [link](https://github.com/jankomag/delaunay_map) How would you classify the lines? Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this can be solved by just removing those lines which are above a certain "distance" in degrees? Please see below:

```r
library(sf)
library(nngeo)
library(ggplot2)

# Points
pts = read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jankomag/delaunay_map/main/points2.csv", sep = ";")
pts = st_as_sf(pts, coords = c("X", "Y"), crs = 4326)

# Lines
neighbors = 5
nearest = st_nn(pts, pts, k = neighbors+1, maxdist = 3500000)
connect = st_connect(pts, pts, nearest) %>% st_as_sf 

# Remove very long lines
l = st_length(st_set_crs(connect, NA))
connect = connect[l < 100, ]

# Plot
ggplot() +
geom_sf(data = connect) +
geom_sf(data = pts, shape = 1, size = 3)
```

[image]